# Resuming the application from where the user left unexpectedly or before.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to resume my application from where the user left before in the previous session. For example,suppose a user is using my application and he is in screen-3 of my application and then he receives a phone call or clicks home button accidentally . Now if he resume my application, I need to resume my application from screen-3 instead of screen-1 i.e from where the user left out previously.

Need Guidance on how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Save state after even view controller change, and when restarting load that state and perform navigation.  Simples.

Comment: Could you please add few lines of code?

Comment: Provide any link for sample example?

Comment: Err, no, that's not how it works on stackoverflow.  Attempt a solution and come back if you have issues.

Comment: This question is too broad. There's a lot to consider if you want an application to return in the same exact state. Start your implementation and ask concrete questions to individual steps if you have any.

Comment: could you please give a clear clarity for your 1st comment.?

Comment: Your question requires to cover many areas, dive into the built-in handling of certain controls (e.g. some have an autosave feature) etc. This cannot be answered in a single question. Start with a strategy how you would make your app state persistent and come back if you have concrete questions for specific parts of it.

Comment: You could dive in for iOS State preservation and restoration. Here's a [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_7_State_Preservation_and_Restoration_Tutorial) and rest you could google for it. This will help you with your goal.